# The source contains no DataRows. error when one iteration in for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a program in Visual Studio where you can read in an excel file in a specific format and where my program converts the data from the excel file in a different format and stores it in a database table.

Below you can find a part of my code where something strange happens

```
//copy schema into new datatable
DataTable _longDataTable = _library.Clone();
foreach (DataRow drlibrary in _library.Rows)
{
    //count number of variables in a row
    string check = drlibrary["Check"].ToString();
    int varCount = check.Length - check.Replace("{", "").Length;
    int count_and = 0;

    if (check.Contains("and") || check.Contains("or"))
    {
        count_and = Regex.Matches(check, "and").Count;
        varCount = varCount - count_and;
    }
    //loop through number of counted variables in order to add rows to long datatable (one row per variable)
    for (int i = 1; i <= varCount; i++)
    {
        var newRow = _longDataTable.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray = drlibrary.ItemArray;
        string j = i.ToString();

        //fill variablename with variable number
        if (i < 10)
        {
            newRow["VariableName"] = "Variable0" + j;
        }
        else
        {
            newRow["VariableName"] = "Variable" + j;
        }
    }
}
```

When `varCount` equals 1, I get the following error message when running the  program after inserting an excel file

> The source contains no DataRows.

I don't know why I can't run the for loop with just one iteration. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Could we have an exemple of input, and output?

Comment: Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: It goes wrong in: for (int i = 1; i <= varCount; i++). When varCount is higher than 1 it works fine, but when varCount equals 1, I get the error message. I input an excel file in the application, but I don't think it would make sense to post that here

Comment: I'd like to know where the exception occurs too, but one glaring problem I see in this code is that you're not adding the row to the _longDataTable in your inner loop when you use `NewRow()`. That's just creating the row instance. You still need to add it using `Rows.Add()`.

Comment: For, `var varCount = 1;`, the loop `for (int i = 1; i <= varCount; i++)` will be run once. There is now way you don't enter the loop.

Comment: I also want to enter the loop, I don't know why it fails when I just run the loop once. It should work, right?

Comment: Off topics but `string j = i.ToString();` and the  `if (i < 10)` is useless, you can simply use [proper string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString). Here it's `i.ToString("D2")`.

Comment: What you describe is inpossible. When `varCount = 1`, the loop is run once. [proof](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vsnxnx). May you use the debugger and [edit] more detail into the question. Like what is the Number of rows in this case? `_library.Rows.Count()` What is the real value of varCount? with proper console.write, Dump or what ever. Because staying on _"can't run the for loop when varCount =1"_ is not good. It's like saying when a equals one, A is not equals to one.

Comment: In the for loop (which I omitted here) I have this code:

Comment: newRow["VariableTableCode"] = tableName;
                    newRow["VariableRowCode"] = rowCode;
                    newRow["VariableColumnCode"] = columnCode;

                    //add edited row to long datatable
                    _longDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

Comment: The _longDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow) gives the error message when varCount equals 1. Does this information help you? Otherwise please ask what other info you want to have